# Is it possible to enable the target app's device admin from the test APK?

Tags: android, android-espresso, device-admin

My app is a device admin, and I enable it by running

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
```

and pressing "Activate" or "Enable."

Can I enable the device admin from my test APK using Espresso?

Comment: Probably not via Espresso, but [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) should work, as what you are doing is really an integration test.

Comment: @CommonsWare, UI Automator helped me. I wish I could share the code. It's a commercial project. if you post an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espresso is pretty much limited to testing your own activities. The "make me a device admin" steps are in another app.

UI Automator is the way to implement cross-app testing. It is not nearly as flexible on the testing front (e.g., you do not have access to the objects of the other app), but you can perform UI actions in other apps to as part of the testing.

Comment: It looks like there is no method for retrieving a view by its id directly. I need to pass the id as a string. Like this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/BySelector.html#res(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)